# Problem aligning simple equal Signs

Tags: equations, align, matrices

I'm very new to Latex but for most problems, I have no problem finding an answer, on this pretty simple one I've been stuck for over an hour and don't seem to find a good solution.
I have 4 different equations where I wanted to align the "=". I tried using {align*} which sadly does not work at all and I am not sure why.

```
\begin{align*}
\centering

A\psi'& = \dfrac{1}{3^n}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -2\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 2\sqrt{2} & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
a\sqrt{2} \\ b \\ c\sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix} 

A^{-1}\psi'& = \dfrac{1}{3^n}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ -2\sqrt{2} & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
a\sqrt{2} \\ b \\ c\sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix} 

B\psi'& = \dfrac{1}{3^n}
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -2\sqrt{2} \\ 0 & 2\sqrt{2} & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
a\sqrt{2} \\ b \\ c\sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix} 

B^{-1}\psi'& = \dfrac{1}{3^n}
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 2\sqrt{2} \\ 0 & -2\sqrt{2} & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
a\sqrt{2} \\ b \\ c\sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix} 

\end{align*}
```

Help is very appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: please always post test documents not just fragments, but you can not have a blank line in `align*` and remove `\centering` which does nothing there. (use `\\ ` not a blank line to separate rows of the alignment)

Comment: Sorry for not making my code compatible. Will think of it next time. David's answer already solved my problem, the blank lines seemed to have caused the problem. Thank you so much for the quick answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You just need to load `amsmath` and use `\\`  not a blank line to end each row of the alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
A\psi'& = \dfrac{1}{3^n}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -2\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 2\sqrt{2} & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
a\sqrt{2} \\ b \\ c\sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix} 
\\
A^{-1}\psi'& = \dfrac{1}{3^n}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ -2\sqrt{2} & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
a\sqrt{2} \\ b \\ c\sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix} 
\\
B\psi'& = \dfrac{1}{3^n}
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -2\sqrt{2} \\ 0 & 2\sqrt{2} & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
a\sqrt{2} \\ b \\ c\sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix} 
\\
B^{-1}\psi'& = \dfrac{1}{3^n}
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 2\sqrt{2} \\ 0 & -2\sqrt{2} & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
a\sqrt{2} \\ b \\ c\sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```